# Carbon/DateTime: The timezone could not be found in the database

Tags: php, datetime, php-carbon

I'm reading a CSV file with datetime fields but when I try to convert the date to `Carbon` by doing `$date = new Carbon($row['date'])` I get one of these errors:

```
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (09/07/2014 16:55:22 MEST) at position 20 (M): The timezone could not be found in the database

DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (24/01/2014 16:57:27 MET) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character
```

Seems PHP does not recognize the MET/MEST timezones. How can I dynamically convert any non-standard timezones to create a Carbon/DateTime object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format may not be in a recognizable format. Use this instead. It will only work with MET, as MEST is not a [valid timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php)

```
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s T', $row['date']);
```

Comment: Beat me to it.. this is what he needs ++

Comment: So what do I do about those invalid formats? For instance, I might get MEST or CEST as well (Middle European Summer Time Same zone) which some systems besides PHP recognize as a valid timezone.

Comment: You might need to create an array of possibilities and their equivalents, and use that to replace the timezone.

Comment: Was hoping there was some standard way of doing so, but `str_replace(['MEST', 'CEST'], ['MET', 'CET'], $row['date'])` will have to do.